# Rif, Rosh, and Rambam about the Techelet

Tags: halacha, rabbis, tzitzis, techeles, shulchan-aruch

The Petil Techelet company (I believe) makes three types of colored strings:

- Raavad- 1 full string of blue
- Tosafot- 2 full strings of blue
- Rambam- 1/2 string of blue

Does the Rif or Rosh mention any method of coloring the strings?

The reason I'm asking this question is to be my own Shulhan Aruch and determine which coloring he would recommend.

Comment: I was under the impression that they stopped selling the Tosfot style due to lack of demand and those who want to wear it just buy two sets of Raavad.

Comment: I would just like to point out, that once you have techelet, and you look into the way you tie the knots. The number of blue strings only works for the type of knot you tie.  Meaning, if you tie like rambam, using two blue strings is impossible.  If you tie like Rav Amran Hagaon, then using 1 full blue string also makes no sense.

Comment: @avi why doesn't that make sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

הלכות קטנות לרא"ש (מנחות) הלכות ציצית סימן ו

ו תנן בראש התכלת [שם דף לח א] התכלת אינו מעכב את הלבן הלבן אינו מעכב את התכלת. פירש"י אף ע"ג דמצוה לתת ב' חוטי תכלת וב' לבן בציצית אפילו הכי אין זה מעכב את זה ואי עביד ארבעתן תכלת או ארבעתן לבן יצא ולכאורה הוי משמע דאין זה מעכב את זה היינו שאם הטיל ב' חוטין מין אחד יצא כי הא דתפילין של יד אינה מעכבת של ראש ושל ראש אינה מעכבת של יד. ונהגו כפירוש רש"י.

In short, the Rosh holds that there should be 2 strings of blue and 2 strings of white.

I am fairly certain the Rif does not comment.

NOTE:

You may find it interesting to note that Rav Yosef Karo in his Beit Yosef does comment on the issue.

בית יוסף אורח חיים סימן יא

ונראה דלא בעי למיחת לפלוגתא במלתא דלא נפקא לן מידי בהאי זימנא

Roughly translated as: And it seems that we don't need to enter into this disagreement [regarding the number of blue strings] as it is a matter which has no practical purpose at this time.

Comment: I think Maran holds like the Tur Rosh etc.

Comment: See the Hatam Sofer O"H 1:1 where I believe he says like the Rambam.

Comment: @HachamGabriel I don't see the proof from the Chatam Sofer. He's just talking aliba the rambam. That doesn't mean he holds like him. Also, why do you think Maran holds 2&2?

Comment: @DoubleAA see the Ksefer Mishne and the other mefaresh I mentioned. Mase Rokeah.

Comment: @DoubleAA Harav Yitzhak Yosef Shelit"a (in his Sefer En Yishak) writes that we even follow the Kesef Mishna for Halacha who holds like ther Rambam here.

Comment: The Beit Yosef there is saying what the Semag is doing, and not talking for himself. That is: "it seems that **he** didn't need to enter into this disagreement".

Comment: "_In short, the Rosh holds that there should be 2 strings of blue and 2 strings of white. I am fairly certain the Rif does not comment._" Based on what is said [in the introduction to Beit Yosef](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Beit_Yosef%2C_Introduction.12) (about what to do in case of a disagreement between two of the his main authorities on a given matter, and the third being silent), the Ramban, the Rashba, the Ran, the Mordechai and Semag should be consulted, for a majority of their opinions. @HachamGabriel

Comment: Apparently, Ramban is 1:7 but the Ran (implied), Rashba and Mordekhai are 4:4. Smag isn't makhria says either one. So we have a rov of 3 vs 1 among the 5. So the halacha is like the Rosh.

Comment: @Gershom ...if "the halacha" is decided by majority of those 3 opinions

Comment: That’s what the bet Yosef the author of the SA says he does in general to resolve a machaloket between the 3 pillars . This shouldn’t not be treated as an exception unless clearly stated by him or ruled by him

Comment: @Gershom a not incomprehensible guess, but a guess all the same. Plus he explicitly declined to use that strategy on this issue even though he could have just done so.

Comment: @DoubleAA because he thought it did not make a difference, not because he did not know how to rule.

Comment: @Gershom not compelling, if he knew the answer why not say so. Do we have any examples in the acharonim of trying to apply the beit yosef's rules to cases he didn't deal with? Seems to me there are too many exceptions in general to make it productive.

Comment: Only sefardic poskim would follow the Bet Yosef methodology to rule in these cases, but interestingly Ashkenazi poskim overwhelmingly rule 2:2 too including the 3 latest big Halacha works in Ashkenazi Jewry: Shulchan Aruch HaRav, Mishna Berura and Aruch HaShulchan.

Comment: @DoubleAA see the Nahagu Ha'Am, Klalei HaPesikah where says that Morrocan Jews among others follow the Derech HaPesak of Maran to rule and even against the own Shulchan Aruch pesak if there is a complete agreement among the 3 or the 5 against SA.

Comment: @Gershom I'm not interested in listing acharonim about the ratio, nor is this the place for that. Just about the idea of "being your own shulchan aruch". Do I understand your last comment correctly that they overrule the shulchan aruch if they have a better sense of which is really the majority of Rif/Rambam/Rosh?? That's incredible

Comment: Yes, they do according to the Morrocan Jewish tradition and Northern Africa.